# Place point over boxplot using plotlyjs and vue

Tags: vue.js, plotly

I'm trying to place point over boxplot, however my attempt results in the point placed next to the boxplot:

```
 data: [
        {
          x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 10],
          type: "box",
          name: "Set 1"
        },
        {
          x: [5],
          name: 'My special marker',
          text: 'Some really interesting hover info',
          marker: {
            size: 5
          }
        },
      ],
      layout: {
        title: 'Revenues',
        font:{
        size:10
        },
        margin: {
          l: 0,
          r: 0,
          b: 15,
          t: 25,
          pad: 0
        },
        height: 90,
        dragmode: "pan"
      },
```

Is it possible to place that point over boxplot using `vue-plotly` library?

Here I recreted the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-plotly-delsw?file=/src/App.vue

EDIT:
For the desired result I need that addiotional point to be on top of the chart like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about x[5]? And where would you like to see it?

Comment: @CristianoSoleti I added example in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set the `size` of the point's marker and the `width` of the bar such that they overlap each other.  For example:

```js
      data: [
        {
          x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 10],
          type: "box",
          name: "Set 1",
          width: 30,
        },
        {
          x: [5],
          name: "My special marker",
          text: "Some really interesting hover info",
          marker: {
            size: 30
          }
        }
      ],
```

[image]

Comment: Thats neat solution, gonna test it further to see if it breaks. Do you know how to enable boxplot tooltips while using this approach? Like the standard boxplot tooltips (q1, q3, min max). Currently it shows only the name of the chart `Set 1`

Comment: [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-customize-plotly-tooltip/332/4) post might help with tooltips, but I'm not sure how to bring this all together with `vue-plotly`.